# Does Sql have any attribute which encrypt while inserting and descrypt while getting data from one column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know is there any attribute or any way where i want to encrypt one column of my table so whenever i am inserting or updating any row in table the columns encrypt that data automatically and while selecting it decrypt and data and get the value in that column.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.certificates where name='EncryptTestCert')
CREATE CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
WITH SUBJECT = 'xyz007'

IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name='TestTableKey') 
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey
WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
```

Now for encryption

```
ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'),@string)
```

For Decrypt

```
DECRYPTBYKEY(@string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing [Transparent Database Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx). This encrypts the data on disk transparently, on-the-fly, w/o requiring any changes to the application. It is available in SQL Server 2008 but requires Enterprise Edition.